# Why cache prompt is not shown?

Tags: swiftui

I found why the cache prompt will not be shown.
If I use the ImageView directly on the ContentView, the cache prompt will not show.  
If I wrap the ImageView with a View, then use the wrapper view on the ContentView, the cache prompt will show.

Here is the working code in the ContentView.swift

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var links =
        [NewsItem(urlString: "https://www.jobyme88.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/50d0-kj-classroom-0.jpg"),
         NewsItem(urlString: "https://www.jobyme88.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/50d0-kj-classroom-1.jpg"),
         NewsItem(urlString: "https://www.jobyme88.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/50d0-kj-classroom-2.jpg"),
         NewsItem(urlString: "https://www.jobyme88.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/50d0-kj-classroom-3.jpg"),
         NewsItem(urlString: "https://www.jobyme88.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/50d0-kj-classroom-4.jpg"),
         NewsItem(urlString: "https://www.jobyme88.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/50d0-kj-classroom-5.jpg"),
         NewsItem(urlString: "https://www.jobyme88.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/50d0-kj-classroom-6.jpg")]
         

    var body: some View {
 
        List(links) { news in
            // working
            NewsListItemView(item: news)

            // not working 
            //NewsImageView(urlString: news.urlString)
        }
    }
}
```

This is the NewsListItemView which is just a wrapper

```
struct NewsListItemView: View {
    var item: NewsItem
    
    var body: some View {
        NewsImageView(urlString: item.urlString)
    }
}
```

This is my cache prompt location.
**NewsImageViewModel.swift**

```
class NewsImageViewModel: ObservableObject {
    static var placeholder = UIImage(named: "NewsIcon.png")
    @Published var image: UIImage?
    var urlString: String?
    
    
    init(urlString: String) {
        self.urlString = urlString
        loadImage()
    }
    
    func loadImage() {
        if loadImageFromCache() {
            return
        }
        loadImageFromURL()
        
    }
    
    func loadImageFromCache() -> Bool {
        guard let cacheIamge = TemporaryImageCache.getShared()[urlString!] else {
            return false
        }
        print("load from cache")
        self.image = cacheIamge
        return true
    }
    
    func loadImageFromURL() {
        print("load from url")
        guard let urlString = urlString else {
            return
        }
        let url = URL(string: urlString)!
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: getResponseFromURL(data:response:error:))
        task.resume()
        
    }
    
    func getResponseFromURL(data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) {
        guard error == nil else {
            print("Error \(error!)")
            return
        }
        
        guard data != nil else {
            print("No founded data")
            return
        }
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            guard let loadedImage = UIImage(data: data!) else {
                print("Not supported data ")
                return
            }
            
            self.image = loadedImage
            TemporaryImageCache.getShared().cache.setObject(loadedImage, forKey: self.urlString! as NSString)
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

**NewsImageView.swift**

```
import SwiftUI

struct NewsImageView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model: NewsImageViewModel
    
    
    init(urlString: String) {
        model = NewsImageViewModel(urlString: urlString)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Image(uiImage: model.image ?? NewsImageViewModel.placeholder!)
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100, alignment: .center)
    }
}
```

**NewsListItemView.swift**

```
struct NewsListItemView: View {
    var item: NewsItem
    
    var body: some View {
        NewsImageView(urlString: item.urlString)
    }
}
```

This is **ImageCache.swift**

```
protocol ImageCache {
    subscript(_ urlString: String) -> UIImage? {get set }
}



struct TemporaryImageCache: ImageCache {
    subscript(urlString: String) -> UIImage? {
        get {
            cache.object(forKey: urlString as NSString)
        }
        set {
            newValue == nil ? cache.removeObject(forKey: urlString as NSString) : cache.setObject(newValue!, forKey: urlString as NSString)
        }
    }
    
    var cache = NSCache<NSString, UIImage>()

}


extension TemporaryImageCache {
    private static var shared = TemporaryImageCache()
    static func getShared() -> TemporaryImageCache {
        return shared
    }
}
```

This is **NewsItem.swift**

```
struct NewsItem: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var urlString: String
}
```

Comment: Would you prepare minimal reproducible example?

Comment: I've edited the post.